# How can I train a model with TensorFlow without giving a formula?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am learning TensorFlow.

I have a question about the code in [Introduction](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/index.html):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Create 100 phony x, y data points in NumPy, y = x * 0.1 + 0.3
x_data = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
y_data = x_data * 0.1 + 0.3

# Try to find values for W and b that compute y_data = W * x_data + b
# (We know that W should be 0.1 and b 0.3, but TensorFlow will
# figure that out for us.)
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y = W * x_data + b

# Minimize the mean squared errors.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# Before starting, initialize the variables.  We will 'run' this first.
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph.
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Fit the line.
for step in range(201):
    sess.run(train)
    if step % 20 == 0:
        print(step, sess.run(W), sess.run(b))

# Learns best fit is W: [0.1], b: [0.3]
```

This program learns best fit of W and b.

If I don't know the formula (`y = W * x_data + b`), how can I train a model?

For example, this is a training set:

```
{input = {{1,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}, ... },  target = {2, 3, 5, ...}}
```

How to train a function(a, b) ~= (a+b)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, we do not know the exact form of the objective formula. Thus, we have to design a function and try to approximate the objective formula by this function.
In neural network, the formula is defined by the network architecture (for example, Multilayer perceptron or Recurrent Neural network) and hyper-parameters (for example, the number of hidden layer, the number of neuron in the hidden layers).

In this particular case for example, you can assume the approximate function has the form of (y = Wa+Ub+C -- a linear perceptron) and train the parameters of this function (W,U,C) to approximate the parameters of the objective formula (y=a+b) using the data given.

Answer (score 0):

A neural network is a universal function approximator: that is, for any function (linear, polynomial, etc.), a neural network can approximate it given enough nodes in hidden layers and an activation function. A non-linear activation function (e.g. sigmoid, tanh, ReLU) will "bend" the linear boundary produced by Wx+b to be non-linear.